# How to determine what list in a foreach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach

In the Output file I'd like it to be formatted with the Share File it is wrong in along with the extension, current IP, and Corrected IP like the below. "Share File 1","Extension","Server IP","Correct IP" where Current IP is the one matching from the Share File and Correct IP is the one listed in the Export file.

Sample Data Below.

My Export:

```
"1000","1608","IP_Phone","1.330D","192.168.1.20","6","","192.1.1.10"
"1005","1608","IP_Phone","1.330D","192.168.1.70","6","","192.1.1.11"
"1010","1608","IP_Phone","1.330D","192.168.1.100","6","","192.1.1.10"
"1080","1608","IP_Phone","1.330D","192.168.1.51","6","","192.1.1.13"
```

Share 1 File:

```
1000, 192.168.1.2, TRUE          ;Test1
1011, 192.168.1.5, TRUE          ;Test2
1005, 192.168.1.100, TRUE          ;Test3
1079, 192.168.1.50, TRUE          ;Test4
```

Share 2 File:

```
1010, 192.168.1.100, TRUE          ;Test5
1020, 192.168.1.5, TRUE          ;Test6
1005, 192.168.1.70, TRUE          ;Test7
1080, 192.168.1.52, TRUE          ;Test8
```

Desired Output File:

```
Share File, Extension, Server IP, Correct IP
Share File 1, 1000, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.20 
Share File 1, 1005, 192.168.1.100, 192.168.1.70
Share File 2, 1080, 192.168.1.52, 192.168.1.51
```

What I have so Far:

```
Clear-Host
$ASAExport = (Import-Csv "C:\app\test\ASAExportNoHeaders.txt" -Header "Extension","2","3","4","Correct IP","6","7","8")
$1 = (Import-Csv "C:\app\test\StationsTest1.txt" -Header "Extension","Server IP","Comment")
$2 = (Import-Csv "C:\app\test\StationsTest2.txt" -Header "Extension","Server IP","Comment")

#$Output = "C:\app\test\Output.txt"
#if (Test-Path($Output)) {Remove-Item $Output}

$ServerList = $1,$2

foreach ($Server in $ServerList) {
    foreach ($ASARow in $ASAExport) {
        foreach ($ServerRow in $Server) {
            if ($ASARow."Extension" -in $ServerRow."Extension") {
                if ($ASARow."Correct IP" -ne $ServerRow."Server IP") {
                    New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
                        "Extension" = $ASARow."Extension"
                        "Correct IP" = $ASARow."Correct IP"
                        "Server IP" = $ServerRow."Server IP"
                    } | Select-Object "Extension","Server IP","Correct IP"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The results I get are as you'd expect. I get Ext, Server IP, and Correct IP.  I need to add the Server it was found in and add it to the `Select-Object`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column `Share File` with the respective value to `$1` and `$2`:

```
$headers = 'Extension', 'Server IP', 'Comment'
$1 = Import-Csv "C:\app\test\StationsTest1.txt" -Header $headers |
     Select-Object *, @{n='Share File';e={'Share File 1'}}
$2 = Import-Csv "C:\app\test\StationsTest2.txt" -Header $headers |
     Select-Object *, @{n='Share File';e={'Share File 2'}}
```

and put it into the result like this:

```
New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
    'Extension'  = $ASARow.Extension
    'Correct IP' = $ASARow.'Correct IP'
    'Server IP'  = $ServerRow.'Server IP'
    'Share File' = $ServerRow.'Share File'
}
```

You don't need a `Select-Object` after `New-Object` BTW. The new object has only the properties you specified anyway.

Comment: Perfect that did the trick however the columns are all out of order can we specify an order?  Share File, Extension, Server IP, Correct IP by chance?  I have it written that way but it's not how the output is coming up.

Comment: Never mind that's where that last select object comes in to define the column order.  Thanks again this is great.

Comment: You can pre-define the order of the properies by making an ordered hashtable. That requires 2 steps, though: `$props = [ordered]@{...}; New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $props`